# Error installing parity

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

I had worked with geth, but getting lots of errors like [last 1000+ blocks not syncing](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1316#issuecomment-255899053), so I have decided to switch to parity.

I was following [One-line Binary Installer](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Setup#one-line-binary-installer), but was hit by:

> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

and if I use:

```
bash https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethcore/scripts/master/install-deps.sh -L
```

I get:

> /bin/sh: 1: cannot open https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethcore/scripts/master/install-deps.sh:
>   No such file

Secondly , I tried  [using docker](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Setup#building-using-docker),but the line `cargo run --release` is giving:

> failed to parse manifest at `/home/pr.singh/parity/Cargo.toml`
>   Caused by:   could not parse input as TOML Cargo.toml:51:9 expected a
>   key but found an empty string Cargo.toml:51:9-51:10 expected `.`, but
>   found `'`

What steps do I need to follow. I have worked with geth, and I have downloaded almost all blockchain data (around 1000 blocks left). How can I switch to parity?

Comment: What operating system are you on? Linux has binaries available. MacOS has a homebrew bottle.